# Is there any API or method to prevent read access (and write) on a dynamic allocated memory?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory-management

Is there any API or method to prevent read access on a dynamic allocated memory?

```
char *ptr = malloc(4);`
strcpy(ptr, "Hello");`
```

Now, i wish to ptr to have no read access and write-protected.
How to accomplish this?

I do not wish to use `mprotect` as it will expect `ptr` to point to mapped memory, and ampping a dynamic memory every time may not be possible.

Comment: Just don't make the pointer visible to other code?

Comment: @fge: No, that can't be possible. It needs to be made visible. But no read-write access. How to accomplish it?

Comment: Why is `mmap` not an option? It gives you exactly a number of pages which you can `mprotect`. In order to preserve memory usage, you could group all of these read-only strings together in the protected pages.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: mmap, munmap - map or unmap files or devices into memory, not dynamically allocated memories

Comment: Can you tell us why you want this? Perhaps there is something else on Linux which can accomplish your goals.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: google for `MAP_ANONYMOUS`.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: Somewhat related to my previous question. I wish to design a memory-overwrite detecting device, point is write can be detected using read-zone technique. But how to detect reads? The method you suggested is used by electric-fence, but it has significant memory overhead, and that's why we wish to design a simple optimized tool.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: Please share us something about that "something else"

Comment: @kingsmasher1, I don't know for sure what your goal is, so I can't say what something else would be.  "protect memory" is not usually a high-level goal, but some approach to that goal. Tell us what type of program you're writing, are you debugging, writing a driver, doing testing, or something else.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: See my last comment on "Blagovest", i have specified my reason (we are designing a memory-overwrite detection tool).

Comment: you may want to wrap it under a struct and have a boolean to set Protected = 0 , but this will definitely add up lots of code. In this way you should still be able to have the variable visible and protected

Comment: @kingsmasher1, have you looked at [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/)?

Comment: @SimonRichter: Not supported by our ARM platform. Do you mean the Valgrind code?

Comment: Neither PC nor ARM MMUs support any access control that is more granular than pages -- so your best bet is to use a virtual machine with a JIT compiler, like Valgrind is. They do have ARM support, so porting the missing bits for your platform (if any) should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

`mprotect` is still the answer. You need a page-aligned allocation with no allocator control information that may need to be writeable -- so allocate your memory by `mmap`ing anonymous memory.

Comment: Every time mapping a dynamically allocated memory, does it have a system overhead or cons? I think it surely has. Also huge memory wastage because one call to malloc will mean allocating a full page. Right?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: you don't have to call `mmap` everytime you need to store a 5-character string. Call `mmap` once to allocate a number of pages, and then store the strings sequentially there until the memory is exhausted. Then you may need to call `mmap` again for more pages.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: Please see my comment above, about why i wish to avoid this.